# No "wlan0" interface in "ip link"

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wifi, ip

Today I noticed that my desktop environment doesn't have any available connections. Checked `ip link` only to see `wlan0` interface completely missing.

Output of `ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp37s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:f0:5d:cb:b0:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp42s0f3u2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8a:64:eb:be:69:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Right now I'm using USB tethering to access the internet, I can only use wireless network at home.

My USB adapter is MW150US. Entry in `lsusb -v`:

```
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2c4e Mercucys INC
  idProduct          0x0102 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 802.11n NIC
  iSerial                 3 00E04C0001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0027
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
            bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

I have manually installed rtl8192eu drivers and they seem to be loaded.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Output of `lshw -c network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
       logical name: enp37s0
       version: 15
       serial: 2c:f0:5d:cb:b0:8d
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.12.1-arch1-1 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:29 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7504000-f7504fff memory:f7500000-f7503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: enp42s0f3u2
       serial: 8a:64:eb:be:69:70
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.12.1-arch1-1 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.57 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: Does `lshw -c network` show all your network adaptors? This should include type, manufacturer, model, 'logical name',etc

Comment: @JeremyBoden, it doesn't, check the edited post

Answer (score 0):

`enp37s0` is an Ethernet interface. Also, the`enp42s0f3u2` is considered as an Ethernet Interface (USB tethering).

To get the WiFi working using your USB dongle, you need to install the [`rtl8192eu`  from AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rtl8192eu/).

Comment: Failed```==> Starting build()...
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.12.1-arch1-1/build M=/home/wispy/.cache/yay/rtl8192eu/src/rtl8192eu-linux-driver  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.12.1-arch1-1/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:2295: modules] Error 2
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
error making: rtl8192eu```